# GROUP_CONCAT make `result,null` to `result,`

Tags: mysql

this is my table:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A72BE.png)

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(roleId) AS roleIds,
    GROUP_CONCAT(gateId) AS gateIds
FROM
    test
GROUP BY
    roleId
```

this is output:

```
    roleIds| gateIds  
    2,2    | 202,306
    3,3    | 654312  
    4      | 315
```

that's what I want:

```
    roleIds| gateIds  
    2,2    | 202,306
    3,3    | 654312,  
    4      | 315
```

Comment: why you only want specific  3     | 654312, ?

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam The second row with `roleId` is null.

Comment: because i use roleIds.split(","), and gateIds.split(","),  finally, i use map.put(roleId_a, gateId_a), map.put(roleId_b, gateId_b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for this:

```
SELECT
    roleId,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(gateId, '')) AS gateIds
FROM
    test
GROUP BY
    roleId
```

The [`IFNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) will change the null value in an empty string, so it will still concatenate.

Comment: I tried it, it was the result i wanted. Although I solved the problem by setting the default value for this field yesterday, i also learned that this function:`IFNULL()`